# Is there a way to download the entire SBIR awards as a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, xml, api, dataframe

For my work I need to create a Python program to download all the results for "awards" from [SBIR](https://www.sbir.gov/sbirsearch/award/all) automatically.

There are as of now, 171616 results.

[image: see here]

I have two possible options. I can download 1,000 at a time but I need to verify that I am not a robot with the [reCAPTCHA](https://www.sbir.gov/json_print/award/all?page=1), therefore I can not automate the download.

Or I could use their API, which would be great! But it only downloads a 100 results when searching for everything available. Is there I way I could iterate through chunks and then compile it into one big JSON file?

This is the [documentation](https://www.sbir.gov/api).

This is [where](https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?) I say `file>save as>filename.json`

[image: see here, only 100 results when importing into Python]

Any help/advice would really help me out.

Comment: unless somebody cracked CAPTCHA otherwise i would say through API is the only option, regarding more result at a time, you can just keep hitting their api in a loop and keep appending the new json into the bigger object.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't know how use the change the chunk from the first 100 to the second 100... and so forth. In my previous project with a different source I was able to loop my increasing the chunk, but that's not working with this one. 

https://www.........ds=d&flds=e&down_chunk=1

https://www.........ds=d&flds=e&down_chunk=2

https://www.........ds=d&flds=e&down_chunk=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, one way to go is to cycle through possible combinations of parameters that you know. E.g, the API accepts parameters 'year' and 'company' among others. You can start with the earliest year that the award was given, say 1990, and cycle through the years up till present.

```
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?year=2010
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?year=2011
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?year=2012
```

this way you'll get up to a 100 awards per year. That's better, however you mentioned that there are 171616 possible results, meaning more than 100 per year, so it won't get all of them. You can use another parameter 'company' in combination.

```
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?year=2010&company=luna
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?year=2011&company=luna
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?year=2010&company=other_company
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?year=2011&company=other_company
```

Now you are getting up to 100 results per company per year. That will give you way more results. You can get the list of companies from another endpoint they provide, which doesn't seem to have a limit on results displayed - https://www.sbir.gov/api/firm.json , watch out though, the json that comes out is absolutely massive and may freeze your laptop. You can use the values from that json for the 'company' parameter and cycle through those.

Of course all of that is a workaround and still doesn't guarantee you getting ALL of the results (although it *might* get them all). My first action would be to try to contact website admins telling them about your problem. A common thing to do for the apis that return a massive list of results is to provide a `page` parameter in the url - `https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?page=2` so that you can cycle through pages of results. Maybe you can persuade them to do that.

Comment: When downloading   and importing the JSON file it gives me 61,440... not exactly 171,616 yet, but its a good step forward. Where did you find this link - https://www.sbir.gov/api/firm.json  ?

Answer (score 1):

I wish they have better documentation. It seems we can do pagination via:

```
https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?agency=DOE&start=100

https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?agency=DOE&start=200

https://www.sbir.gov/api/awards.json?agency=DOE&start=300
```